# jQuery Animation not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let me start by saying that I am completely new to HTML, CSS, and jQuery. I'm learning HTML and CSS in college and I want to teach myself jQuery so I can be ahead of the game.

I am simply trying to animate some text (move the text up and scale the font size) but, for some reason I can't get the text to animate at all. Is there something that I am doing incorrectly?

Also, I've searched around and tried to fix this problem on my own but, I can't seem to get anything to work. This is my last resort.

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <script src="modernizr-2.js"></script>

    <script>$("#logo").animate({top:'0px',fontSize:'200%'}, 800);</script>

    <title>Home</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_layout.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="logo" class="title">Test</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.title {
    font-size: 450%;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    right: 35%;
    top: 25%;
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MWKrM/1/

I am using Firefox on a Mac.

Comment: Works for me... Im on windows with chrome

Comment: What's the problem? The animation runs correctly on your fiddle (and I'm using Firefox aswell)

Comment: The fiddle seems to be working for me, what's not working for you?

Comment: works for me as well.

Comment: Works for me on Linux, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: you need to wrap the script with $(document).ready if you put the script on head

Comment: My problem is that the text does not move or animate at all. I thought I was doing everything correctly and also like @nims said it works fine on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script is firing before the logo element is added to the DOM.  You'll want to wrap your jquery code in the document.ready() method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logo").animate({top:'0px',fontSize:'200%'}, 800);
});
```

This will delay the execution of your code until the page has fully loaded the DOM, at which point your animation should perform correctly.

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately the fiddle in the question was not a good representation of the issue.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what was wrong. I have to wait 6 minutes before I can accept your answer

Comment: @isherwood Yeah the fiddle really messed everything us since it includes doc.ready.

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWKrM/4/)

Make your script with in the `$(document).ready(function(){..}`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#logo").animate({
      top:'0px',
      fontSize:'200%'
   }, 800);
 });
```

Comment: What did you get down voted for..? in my opinion your code is more easy to read then any of the other answers. Maybe I am the last person who cares about maintaining code later down the rode. :p +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

You need tell your HTML that you're starting jQuery, bro.

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#logo").animate({top:'0px',fontSize:'200%'}, 800);
})
</script>
```

Comment: What an odd way to explain it. :-)